# Bootstrap accordion aria-expanded doesnt work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, accordion

i am using bootstrap 4 accordion. i want as initial state to have all the cards collapsed. I set aria-expanded to false but all the cards appeared expanded.

```
<div id="accordion">
            <!-- ko foreach: $root.Addons() -->
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-bind="text:name, attr: { 'data-target': '#collapsible' +  $index(),'aria-controls': 'collapsible' +  $index() }"></button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'collapsible' + $index() }" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the classes as they are in the collapsed state.

1) Add class `collapsed` with `btn btn-link` in the button element

2) Remove class `show` from `collapse show` in the div element

I have updated the code with the above changes. It should keep the accordion in collapsed state initially.

```
<div id="accordion">
            <!-- ko foreach: $root.Addons() -->
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-bind="text:name, attr: { 'data-target': '#collapsible' +  $index(),'aria-controls': 'collapsible' +  $index() }"></button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'collapsible' + $index() }" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```